# Modify regex in a script that highlights certain words in a text by adding span classes to them

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a code that highlights certain words, using a regex.

Here it is:

```
function addRegEx($word){
        return "/\b(\w+)?".$word."(\w+)?\b/i";
    }
    function highlight($word){
        return "<span class=\"highlighted\">".$word[0]."</span>";
    }
    function customHighlights($searchString,$toHighlight){
        $searchFor = array_map('addRegEx',$toHighlight);
        $result = preg_replace_callback($searchFor,'highlight',$searchString);
        return $result;
    }
```

Lets say I use the function **customHighlights** to searc for the word **"car"** in a certain text:

Using the boundary - \b - method, the script searches for the word car in the text.

In the regex, I have added **(\w+)?** in front and after the word, so the script would match words that contain **"car"** - *cars, sportcars, etc...*

The problem is, it messes up the inner html, for example:

```
This is a great car. Click here for <a href="http://cars.com">more</a>
```

**The script will match the word car in the url of the link above, adding span classes to it and messing up the html.**

How would you modify the regex and avoid this?

Comment: I use the highlight functon just for excerpts -- maybe I could keep it simple and apply it jsut to the part of the excerpt which has no link.

Comment: this problem is quite difficult to do it right especially if you want to take in account every HTML tag. Do you want to take in account every tag or just the `a` tag ?

Comment: In my excerpts I have a one H3 tag and p tags -- so they won't break because they cannot contain the word car for example. Apart from them, there is the url which can contain that word - so I could ignore it and solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression that searches for the word after the last `>` or beginning of text, but part between this and the word may not contain a tag start `<`.

See this [codepad](http://codepad.org/Crrke9bq)

**Code**

```
<?php
$str = 'This is a great car. Click here for <a href="http://cars.com">more cars</a>';
$word = 'car';
$exp = "/((^|>)[^<]*)(\b(\w+)?".$word."(\w+)?\b)/i";
$repl = "\\1<span class=\"highlighted\">\\3</span>";
var_dump(preg_replace($exp, $repl, $str));
?>
```

**Output**

```
string(141) "This is a great <span class="highlighted">car</span>. Click here for <a href="http://cars.com">more <span class="highlighted">cars</span></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider processing the text highlighting on client-side using Javascript? jQuery or similar could allow you to iterate over nodes to find where to highlight instead of working with the raw HTML.
I can't help you much with the regular expression though.

Comment: This is a great workaround - if everything fails I'll implement it, it's just I get the word to highlight serverside. I'd have to echo them into a javascript data object - and work from there